# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, registration

I am totally new in the Ruby on Rails. I have tried to show an message while register. Please check my controller and view code -

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :success]

  def login
    render layout: false
  end
  def register
    render layout: false
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create_register
    @user = User.new(create_user_params)
    #raise @user.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @users, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :success, status: :created, location: @users }
      else
        format.html { render :register }
        format.json { render json: @ruby_win_source.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def success
    raise @user.inspect
  end


  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :image, :dob, :photo, :address)
  end
end
```

register.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(@user) do |f| %>
         <% if @user.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
              <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
get    'register'   => 'users#register'
post   'register'   => 'users#create_register'
```

URL - http://localhost:3000/register

While I am loading this page I got this error message -

[image]

I searched in google and getting some same issue link. Follow step but my problem still not resolved. Please help me :(

Comment: `<% if @user.errors.any? %>` change it to `<% if @user && @user.errors.any? %>` - see if still you see the same  error or not ?

Comment: Yes this issues fixed. But i am getting another error `cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext`

Comment: @dkp thanks for commenting here. Your comment also right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 lines in your register method are reversed. Try this:

```
def register
  @user = User.new
  render layout: false
end
```

Comment: Yes Dear, You are right. May I know why I reverse that? Can you please describe your answer.

Comment: As soon as you call the render method, the template is rendered which in your case, looks for the user variable, but that variable has not been set.

Comment: Exactly what margo said. You were calling render before instantiating the user.

Answer (score 1):

In the create_register method you create a new user calling

```
@user = User.new(create_user_params)
```

but your strong params method is named user_params. Try changing the above line to

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: Ohh!! sorry I forgot to change that. Acautlly I was `create_user_params `action. I have deleted this while posted this question. :(

Comment: Please update your question accordingly as it is quite misleading.

Comment: I have problem in `register` action. `create_register` action is the different things. So no need to update question. I got my answer. Thank you for answering here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the method `errors` on a nil class. Very common issue when doing Rails. This line

`<%= form_tag(@user) do |f| %>
         <% if @user.errors.any? %>`

is looking for a `@user` object. You did try to declare one here:

`def register
  render layout: false
  @user = User.new
end`

But based on the error I'm going to presume it failed. Not seeing a migration for the user table I'm guessing you didn't create one? To create a new `User` object for an active record class you need to run a migration against the database so that there is a table to work with.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

I am also not seeing a model here. To user `User.new` you also need a model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Now there is one other tool that will making working in Rails much, much easier for you.

http://pryrepl.org/

Coolest tool ever. simply install the pry gem, require `pry` and place a newline with `binding.pry` wherever you need to *pry* into the code and you can play around directly with the code. For this instance I would do it like this.

`` def register
  render layout: false
  require `pry`; binding.pry;
  @user = User.new
end ``

Then go to the terminal you are running your server and you are inside the code. Then try the failing part of the code. `@user = User.new` It will give you a much more illuminating error message.